# Select from sql With Multi operator

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have a code to search items from sql data base

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("
          SELECT * 
          FROM ClothesBarcodeBalances 
          WHERE StoID='" & StorageIDtxt.Text & 
          "'AND ItemCode Like'%" & TextBox7.Text & "%'
             OR FactoryCode Like'%" & TextBox7.Text & "%'
             OR ItemName Like'%" & TextBox7.Text & "%'", dbconnect)
```

i need to search with like `Where StorageID=StorageIDtxt.text`

but when running code it give me all Storages not the storage i select on the sql query

What the wrong with query ??
i hope find help

Comment: Your lack of () is an issue here because you are searching by storage OR something like. Another issue in your code is it prone to [SQL Inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: looks like AND/OR combination issue. assuming you don't want to change any of your conditions, you can filter in advance the table you are selecting from. something like: SELECT * 
FROM (select * from ClothesBarcodeBalances where StorageID = '" & StorageIDtxt.Text & "') as some_table_alias, this way the where clause will already be applied to a filtered result set

Answer (score 3):

This have to do with operator precedense `AND` operator resolve first

Right now:

```
  WHERE A and B or C or D
```

is equivalent to

```
  WHERE (A and B) or C or D
```

So add parenthesis to get

```
  WHERE A and (B or C or D)
```

Also use parametrized query https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Otherwise you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
da = New SqlDataAdapter("
          SELECT * 
          FROM ClothesBarcodeBalances 
          WHERE StoID='" & StorageIDtxt.Text & 
          "'AND (ItemCode Like'%" & TextBox7.Text & "%'
             OR FactoryCode Like'%" & TextBox7.Text & "%'
             OR ItemName Like'%" & TextBox7.Text & "%')", dbconnect)
```

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR` (BTW not only in SQL but also in (almost) all programming languages (also VB!) and logic per se), so it got you everything with a matching store ID or one of the other conditions matching.

You also should consider using parametrized queries. Your application might be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.